# C++ references, addresses, pointers

Tags: c++, object, reference

I see a function definition that looks like this

```
ClassName::Read(myObjectClass &temp)
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
myObjectClass *myObj;
ClassName::Read(&myObj);
```

but that is incorrect. What is the proper way to call it? It needs to be of type `myObjectClass&`

Comment: Just be careful that if the object 'myObj' is not created in the calling function (e.g. new myObjectClass), the Read will write to some undefined address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As James correctly points out, the correct syntax is `*myObj`. The point is that `&myObj` gives you the address of `myObj`, which has a type of `myObjectClass**`. You want instead to *dereference* `myObj` to get at the instance of `myObjectClass` to which it points, hence you use `*`.

Incidentally, as it stands at the moment, using `*myObj` would cause undefined behaviour, since `myObj` itself has not been initialised. If you don't need to dynamically allocate a `myObjectClass`, you might be better off just doing this:

```
myObjectClass myObj;
ClassName::Read(myObj);
```

If dynamic allocation is a must, then you can do e.g.

```
myObjectClass *myObj = new myObjectClass;
ClassName::Read(*myObj);
//...
delete myObj;
```

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
ClassName::Read(*myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
myObjectClass myObj;
ClassName::Read(myObj);
```

You don't have to use pointers and dynamic allocation everywhere. C++ is not Java.